# Why is the martyrdom of the daughter of the Prophet, Fatima al-Zahra, commemorated at three different times?

Tags: shiism, martyr, fatima-zahra

In the Shia school of thought, the martyrdom of the daughter of the Prophet is commemorated at three different times; the last one today, on 3rd of Jumada al-Thani.

Why is it that "there are three different times for the Wafat of Fatima al-Zahra"?

Answer (score 2):

There can be diverse reasons for that, such as:

- Narrating of historical events was not like now (to be written…), and
  actually the narrating of the events was often verbally, consequently
  perhaps wrongly …
- On the other hand, the Muslims were busy in fighting at that time,
  and as a result were not so worry to register the dates of events
  exactly.
- The conflicts which were created after the Prophet passed away, can
  be considered as a reason for the distortion of many facts ...

And so on.

---

Reference:

- [www.farsnews.com](http://www.farsnews.com/newstext.php?nn=13921224001299)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the ambiguity. We don't know exact time of martyrdom. Among of several guessed time from history-writers these three times have more logical proofs.

Tip: search for the way hadzrat Fatima has martyrdomed, and you find out.

Comment: This answer would benefit form references

Answer (score 0):

Why is the martyrdom of the daughter of the Messenger of God (PBUH) Fatemeh Al-Zahra (PBUH) held at three different times?
There is a difference of opinion among the historical books about the number of days that Hazrat Siddiqah Tahereh, peace be upon him, was alive after the death of her noble father. Some historians, such as Ya'qubi, have mentioned this period as forty days, and others, such as Aisha, the daughter of Abi Bakr, have mentioned this period as six months, and others as eight months. Among Shiite scholars, there are two well-known and accepted dates: one seventy-five days after the death of the Prophet (PBUH) and the other ninety-five days.
It is narrated from Imam Baqir (as) that he said: It is true that the time of the death of Siddiqah Kobra, peace be upon him, was three months after the death of the Holy Prophet of Islam, peace be upon him and his family.

Ref: https://www.mefda.ir/news/190577/%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AE-%D8%AF%D9%82%DB%8C%D9%82-%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%AA-%D8%AD%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%B2%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D8%B3-%DA%86%D9%87-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA